# GCC evaluation of compound statement

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, gcc-statement-expression

I found the following construct, where a variable is assigned to what seems to be a compound statement, `foo`, in a driver. For comparison, `bar` yields undefined behaviour be treating the same code as a proper function. It doesn't seem to conform with my understanding of the C language and its preprocessor, so I suspect that it is a GCC extension. What is the logic executed here? (See output [here](http://ideone.com/UMVHgb).)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define foo(c) ({ int x = c; x; })

int bar(char c) {
    int x = c;
    x;
}

int main(void) {
    int x = foo('0');
    int y = bar('A');
    printf("%d\n%d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
48
0
```

Comment: As you already suspect a gcc extension, why did you not check the documentation before asking? What else did you do to find out?

Comment: @Olaf I did try extensive searching, but couldn't find the keywords to yield a result. I was able to find sources for the UB I suspected from the function version given, but this wasn't quite the same as the macro version. I browsed through the GCC manual, but didn't find the specific reference to it as there are sufficiently many extensions to make a linear search difficult. Moreover, I also consulted with some colleagues in person who were unaware of this construct. I believe I conducted enough research to merit this question.

Comment: Less than 5 minutes of searching leads to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs which includes the terms "statement" and "declaration" which is exactly what you have above. How to properly search is a basci skill when it comes to programmning and many other fields. Sidenote: see [ask], you should show your effort in your question!

Comment: Knowing now the answer, it is trivial to find this. My searching abilities seem to have failed me yesterday. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different things involved here.

Firstly, the so called "statement expression" `({ int x = c; x; })`, which is a GCC extension. This expression in GCC evaluates to the well-defined value of `x`. The value it evaluates to is defined by the last expression inside the `({...})`, which is `x` in your case. (BTW, the preprocessor has little to do with it. You don't have to involve preprocessor to use statement expressions in GCC.)

Secondly, your function `bar`, which is declared to return `int` but lacks a return statement. This has nothing to do with any extensions. This function does not return any defined value. If the calling code attempts to use the value returned by `bar`, the behavior is undefined. The `x` expression at the end of `bar` is just a no-op that does not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a GCC extension and it is described in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). Where an expression is expected, you can supply a brace-surrounded block as a valid expression whose value is the last expression in the block.

C does not automatically insert a `return` in an expression statement at the end of a function, so `bar` is indeed UB. GCC does not implement any extension which does that either. But the following would be legal with the GCC extension:

```
int bar(char c) {
  return ({
    int x = c; 
    x; 
  });
}
```