# Can't understand statement (void)(x == y) and 1; in linux typecheck macro

Tags: c, linux, gcc, types, linux-kernel

In linux 5.4.21 source code include/linux/irqflags.h,

```
#define raw_local_save_flags(flags)         \
    do {                        \
        typecheck(unsigned long, flags);    \
        flags = arch_local_save_flags();    \
    } while (0)
```

and in include/linux/typecheck.h

```
#define typecheck(type,x) \
({  type __dummy; \
    typeof(x) __dummy2; \
    (void)(&__dummy == &__dummy2); \
    1; \
})
```

I can't understand how the typecheck macro works. So the typecheck macro makes a variable __dummy having type `type`, and another variable __dummy2 with the same type with `x`. It then compares the address of those two variables. I guess putting `(void)` makes the comparison statement not make error.. but what does this comparison do? How can two variables have same address? and what is the last state `1;` ?  And what effect does this macro have in the `raw_local_save_flags` macro? (related to how it is called..) Can somebody explain it to me please?  Thanks!

Comment: This comparison does nothing if the types match, and makes the compiler complain if they don't.

Comment: I think it will only generate a compiler warning. TBH, `raw_local_save_flags` and similar macros that save and restore irq flags ought to be changed to generate a compiler error.

Comment: Note that the cast to `void` is merely to avoid a possible compiler warning about a statement with no effect; most compilers will suppress such a warning if the expression is cast to `void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison `&__dummy == &__dummy2` is only permitted if the objects are of the same type, so a compiler will complain if they are not.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014660/gcc-evaluation-of-compound-statement) about Compound Statements.
You can supply a brace-surrounded block (a compound statement) as a valid expression whose *value is the last expression in the block.*

So in `({ int x = c; x; })` the value of the expression is evaluated as `x;`